# Reading the text on screen using python

Tags: python, pyautogui

How do I get the text from a text file and save it as a variable in python? I tried saving it as an image and then using the pytesseract.image_to_string() but it did not seem to work

Comment: Hi there, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Take a look at open() and read()

Answer (score 0):

You can try the pickle module of python: [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle) [pickle example RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-pickle-module/)

I am posting an example, not sure it is what you are looking for, my intents

came from the 'Variables are containers for storing data values' meaning:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



import pickle

# reads your textfile.txt and stores as 'variable'

with  open("textfile.txt","r") as textfile: 
            variable=textfile.read()
           
print('\ntextfile.txt content: ',variable)
                
textfile.close()

#dumps the variable to a binary pickle serialized file

with open("variablefile.var", 'wb') as variablefile:
    pickle.dump(variable, variablefile)

#loads a new variable from the binary pickle serialized file

with open("variablefile.var", 'rb') as variablefile:
    variableloaded = pickle.load(variablefile)
    
    
print('variable loaded from file', variableloaded)

print('\nvariable loaded type from file', type(variableloaded))
```

or You can store your data in a dictionary and save them in JSON format (JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. This format is a popular method of storing data in key-value arrangements so it can be parsed easily later.) [python JSON documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



import json

# create empty dictionary

variables_dict = {}


# reads your textfile.txt and stores as 'textfile.txt' inside the dictionary

with  open("textfile.txt","r") as textfile: 
            variables_dict["text.file.txt"]= textfile.read()
           
print('\nvariables_dict : ',variables_dict)
                
textfile.close()

#save the dictionary as a json file 'variables.json'

with open('variables.json', 'w') as variablessaved:
    json.dump(variables_dict, variablessaved)
    

#read the dictionary as a json file 'variables.json'

    
with open('variables.json', 'r') as variablesloaded:
    loaded_dict = json.load(variablesloaded)
    


print('\nloaded dictionary : ' , loaded_dict)
```

Again I am not sure about what you were looking for.